# Power BI Issue: Calculated Items Misbehaving When Filtering

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, tabular-editor

I'm encountering a perplexing issue in my Power BI report that involves calculated items. Any insight or suggestion is much appreciated.

**Link to the PBIX file:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M_jHZchjlJ_HKTNgoR9eupGFtnyG_Zet/view?usp=drive_link

**Data Model:**

- FactData
- DimProductHierarchy
- DimVersionName1 (disconnected table)
- DimVersionName2 (disconnected table)

**Measures:**

- [Volume] = SUM(FactData[Volume]

**Table Chart1:**
Category column - DimProductHierarchy[Level 1]
Value - "Version 1", which is a calculated item I created in Tabular Editor

**Table Chart2:**
Category column - DimProductHierarchy[Level 1]
Value - "Version 2", which is a calculated item I created in Tabular Editor

**Slicer1**
Used column - DimVersionName1[Version Name]
Only applied to - Table Chart 1

**Slicer2**
Used column - DimVersionName2[Version Name]
Only applied to - Table Chart 2

**Calculated Item 1 (Version 1):**

```
VAR SelectedVersion1 = SELECTEDVALUE(DimVersionName1[Version Name])
VAR MyFilter = FILTER(ALL(FactData[Version Name]), FactData[Version Name] = SelectedVersion1)
VAR Result = CALCULATE(SELECTEDMEASURE(), MyFilter)
RETURN
    Result
```

**Calculated Item 2 (Version 2):**

```
VAR SelectedVersion2 = SELECTEDVALUE(DimVersionName2[Version Name])
VAR MyFilter = FILTER(ALL(FactData[Version Name]), FactData[Version Name] = SelectedVersion2)
VAR Result = CALCULATE(SELECTEDMEASURE(), MyFilter)
RETURN
    Result
```

**Other Details:**

- **FactData** and **DimProductHierarchy** are connected with the Many-to-One relationship.

**The Problem:**
When I click on a category in **Table Chart 1**, **Table Chart 2** turns blank, whereas I need **Table Chart 2** to show just that selected category.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you able to share the dax for `SELECTEDMEASURE()` for `SelectedVersion1` and `SelectedVersion2`? If so, please update the question above with the same.

Comment: @SamNseir Thanks for asking. The SELECTEDMEASURE() has [Volume] as its underlying measure - the formula is already included in the original question. Same with SelectedVersion1 and SelectedVersion2. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample PBIX, when selecting a row in Chart 1, Chart 2 displays nothing - not the same value as Chart 1 as per your problem statement above. So I cannot give you explanation on that. (Feel free to update the given pbix replicating this behaviour and I'll happily take a look.)

For context, you have visual filters applied and so when selecting a row, that context is also applied to other visuals. Since Visual 1 has "Name is Version1" and Visual 2 has "Name is Version2", you will see nothing in Visual 2 when selecting a row in Visual 1.

**Suggested solution to give multiple options**
Create a new Calculated Item to your Calculation Group with the following:

```
Version = 
  var v1 = CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDMEASURE(),
    FILTER(
      ALL(FactData[Version Name]),
      FactData[Version Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(DimVersionName1[Version Name])
    )
  )
  var v2 = CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDMEASURE(),
    FILTER(
      ALL(FactData[Version Name]),
      FactData[Version Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(DimVersionName2[Version Name])
    )
  )
  RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISFILTERED(DimVersionName1[Version Name]) && ISFILTERED(DimVersionName2[Version Name]), v1 - v2,
    ISFILTERED(DimVersionName1[Version Name]), v1,
    ISFILTERED(DimVersionName2[Version Name]), v2,
    SELECTEDMEASURE()
  )
```

Then update the visual filters for the three Matrix visuals to "Name is Version". Then ensure Slicer 1 is only applied to Matrix 1 and Matrix 3, Slicer 2 is only applied to Matrix 2 and Matrix 3 - with Matrix 3 being your diff.

[image]

Once more, **if** you did want to show these in one visual, then you can add `'MyCG'[Name]` as the Column to your Matrix, and have both slicers applied to the same Matrix. This would give you something like (perhaps rename `Version` to `Version Difference`):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sam. Tried already. That doesn't work, as it removes all the filters, even those in the visuals, so I have totals for my metric in each row.

Comment: Possible to share a PBIX with sample or mock data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Yes, I can. Can you explain how to send it, please?

Comment: Upload it to a public share like One Drive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc... Then share link here or in the question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M_jHZchjlJ_HKTNgoR9eupGFtnyG_Zet/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Thanks for sharing the PBIX, it helps heaps. Answer updated above.

Comment: Thanks again, Sam. Unfortunately, I can't use the calculated group as a column, as I need to separate table charts, each tied to its own slicer. This is a very simplified version of a larger report, where Table Chart1 and Table Chart 2 are two P&L reports, and there's also Table Chart 3 there, so when a client selects versions for the first 2 charts, the third one shows the difference for all the metrics (I only kept [Volume] for simplicity here).

Comment: Yes, sorry, when I turn off the interaction between the Version 1 Slicer and Table Chart 2, and the interaction between Version 2 Slicer and Table Chart 1, then filtering Table Chart 1 makes the second table blank, but when the interactions are On, then filtering the Table Chart 1 forces Table Chart 2 change its values.

Comment: I think I understand. Updated the answer above.

Comment: How did this go? Let us know if you need anything else. If all good, then please Accept answer for the benefit of all.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thank you, I'll check ASAP and let you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Sam, your solution solved my problem. I accepted the answer.